# Why do I get :cannot start container: Error getting container from device devicemapper: Error Mounting Invalid Argument everytime I start container

Tags: docker

All my docker containers suddenly exist. I try to restart the container and get following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 1559: Error getting container 1559fdbc6c2ab8f12d9efe1a066880ddedb2c424d3a3ed8a1f8a2eb181e1c3ba from driver devicemapper: Error mounting '/dev/mapper/docker-253:2-33554560-1559fdbc6c2ab8f12d9efe1a066880ddedb2c424d3a3ed8a1f8a2eb181e1c3ba' on '/data/docker/devicemapper/mnt/1559fdbc6c2ab8f12d9efe1a066880ddedb2c424d3a3ed8a1f8a2eb181e1c3ba': invalid argument
```

Here is docker info

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker info
Containers: 9
Images: 189
Storage Driver: devicemapper
Pool Name: docker-253:2-33554560-pool
Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
Backing Filesystem: xfs
Data file: /dev/loop0
Metadata file: /dev/loop1
Data Space Used: 7.367 GB
Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
Data Space Available: 54.15 GB
Metadata Space Used: 11.58 MB
Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
Metadata Space Available: 2.136 GB
Udev Sync Supported: true
Deferred Removal Enabled: false
Data loop file: /data/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
Metadata loop file: /data/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
Library Version: 1.02.107-RHEL7 (2015-10-14)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.703 GiB
Name: localhost.localdomain
ID: UBGK:AERA:AYMM:XB6P:XCOG:MUGB:NKZM:GSIY:AH25:UGN7:FUF3:ID44
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

I tried to restart the docker and it still didn't work.

I cannot remove all the containers or images.

The disk used to run out of space.

My docker version is 1.8

What can I do to recover my container?

Really thank you for your help!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your `docker info` command output?

If your Docker Root dir -

> /var/lib/docker (default)

is under the same disk running out of space as mentioned by you then you wouldn't be able to pull image or run docker containers. Try to clean up some space and then you may be able to recover your container. BTW when your say recover - Are you writing any data into the container?

Any specific reason to be on older version of Docker?

The recommended storage driver for Docker is overlay2 & FYI the devicemapper storagedriver is deprecated in 18.09 release and would be removed in future release.

Read more about storage drivers [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/)

Comment: Thank you.  I have added my docker info.  docker root dir and data are mounted to different directories. /var has enough space.  docker cannot upgrade for history reason, but I would try to upgrade it some time